# LIKE Query matching

Tags: php, sql

I am using the following SQL query:

```
LIKE '%"$_POST[var]"%'
```

When users do a search with `flat screen` it doesn't return results with 'flat' OR 'screen' ONLY the exact match.

What is the best approach?

Comment: What are you searching against? What were you trying that doesn't work? Why isn't what you have acceptable?

Comment: Specify DB model please. Also: "SQL query", not "PHP query".

Comment: field LIKE "flat screen" will return something when your field is exactly "flat screen", users should put wild characters like % or _. For example "%at" will give you at,cat,and that. "_at" will give you cat and hat but not at and that.

Comment: i think your problem is the ' and " in your statement...what if you try:  LIKE '%17 inch flat screen%'...now that will only find records where the description contains that exact term

Comment: I just want to be able to search for any of the strings in the query, NOT just the whole word match.

Comment: meaning if you want to find any record that contains any of those words you would need to do:  LIKE '%17%' AND LIKE '%inch%' AND LIKE '%flat%' and LIKE '%screen%'..the way you have it now you will only get records that contain "17 inch flat screen"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use a regular expression, eg

`where column~'flat\s+screen'`

Comment: Please explain further. This sounds like a better solution.

Comment: Well, regular expressions are a sophisticated--and powerful--method of pattern matching.  There are several tutorials for regular expressions--a quick Google search for regular expressions in php turned up http://www.webcheatsheet.com/php/regular_expressions.php which seems to be pretty decent.  There are also interactive regular expression tutorials (such as http://www.perlfect.com/articles/regextutor.shtml) that let you tinker around and experiment with them.

Comment: In the example above, "\s" represents a white space, and "+" is a quantifier denoting "one or more of the previous character".  So, the regular expression above looks for a match of the word "flat" followed by one or more spaces, followed by "screen".

Answer (score 1):

The approach you are using will probably work, but it will be slow.

For text searches it might be better to use a full text index. There is support for this built into most databases and you could also look at an external indexing engine such as [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/) or [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

You probably need [Full-Text Search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html).

Note: That link is for MySQL, but other databases have Full-Text too.